# Angular 2 POST to Laravel Rest API doesnt unless port number is changed

Tags: angularjs-directive, angular, laravel-5, angular2-services, angular2-forms

I have made a laravel and angular 2 API - It basically does a post request to a laravel backend API. Everything works perfectly when I run php artisan serve from the root folder and npm start from the public folder, the public folder is served via port 3000 and artisan serves the api via port 8000

this is how my service file looks with the default artisan port 8000 and localhost as the API url

```
    import {Http, Headers, Response} from "@angular/http"
    import {Injectable} from "@angular/core"
    import {ICourse} from "../interfaces/ICourse"
    import 'rxjs/Rx';
    import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
    import {Observer} from 'rxjs/Observer';
    import 'rxjs/add/operator/share';
    import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

    @Injectable()
    export class Api {
        apiUrl: string = "http://localhost:8000/api/courses/";
        headers: Headers = new Headers;
        courses$: Observable<ICourse[]>;
        private _coursesObserver: Observer<ICourse[]>;
        private _dataStore: {
            courses: ICourse[]
        };

        constructor(private _http: Http) {
            this.headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
            this.headers.append('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');
            this.courses$ = new Observable<ICourse[]>(observer => this._coursesObserver = observer).share();        
            this._dataStore = { courses: [] };
        }

        public createCourse(course) {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                this._http.post(this.apiUrl, course, {
                    headers: this.headers
                }).map((res: Response) => res.json()).subscribe(
                        (res) => {
                            resolve(res);
                            console.log('api succeeds');
                        },
                        (error) => {
                            alert('error');
                            reject(error);
                        }
                    );
            })
        }


    }
```

when I change the api url to a fully qualified domain like http://www.example.com/api/course no only does it do a GET request rather than a POST but it doesnt do anything at all... ive went through the source code trying to figure out what the heck is going on but I am literally stumped.. Anyone come across this before ? To be noted also is that I can use a real domain however i have to serve php artisan from a different port

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you change apiUrl property to that of the live server?
You also need a token. You can add `{{ csrf_field() }}` to the top of your page that houses the angular app, but you need it, just like with any post request in laravel. I havent really dug into sending responses between two seperate servers but if you are going that route jwt might be the trick.

I wrote a small article on this a little while back, its not super thorough, but could help [check it out](http://paulthorpe.co/blog/a-simple-api-between-angular-2-and-laravel)